# Trouble getting Cake PHP JsHelper to work

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I seem to be beaten at the very first hurdle on this one, I can't seem to get a basic "Hello world" going on in cake PHP.

in /app/Controller/MyController.php I have:

```
public $helpers = array('Js' => array('Jquery'), 'Html', 'Form');
public $components = array('RequestHandler');
```

in /app/View/Layouts/default.ctp I have:

```
echo $this->Html->script('//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js');
echo $this->fetch('script');        
echo $this->Js->writeBuffer();
?></head>
```

in /app/View/My/index.ctp I have:

```
$this->Js->alert('HelloWorld');
```

but I get no alerts! If I try:

```
echo $this->Js->alert('HelloWorld');
```

it prints out to the browser: (double quotes instead of the typed single quotes!?)

```
alert("HelloWorld");
```

but not wrapped in < script > tags or even a $(document).ready(function(){});

Have I missed something out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JsHelper is pretty useless to be honest.  I don't even bother with it properly, I just include JavaScript in my site as I would normally, but using Cake's methods to keep it within the framework.

Example layout would have jQuery included in the `<head>` like this:

**app/View/Layouts/default.ctp**

```
<head>

<?php
    // Include jQuery
    echo $this->Html->script('jquery-1.8.2.min');

    // Want to send some glabal values to your scripts?
    $this->Js->set(array(
        'TEST' => 'Hello World',
        'ROOT' => $this->Html->url( '/', true)
    ));
    echo $this->Js->writeBuffer(array('onDomReady' => false));

    // Include any other scripts you've set
    echo $this->fetch('script');
?>

</head>
```

Then in your view, you might want to include a specific script for that page:

**app/View/Pages/test.ctp**

```
<?php echo $this->Html->script('test.js'); ?>
```

And you just keep all your JavaScript as usual in an external script:

**app/webroot/js/test.js**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    /**
     * Alert the value we set in our layout.  All JS vars that have been
     * set are available in your JavaScript via the window.app object.
     */
    alert(window.app.TEST + ' sent from ' + window.app.ROOT);

});
```

Answer (score 2):

The general consensus is don't bother using the JsHelper, and is likely being removed in Cake 3 in any case.

I would put `echo $this->Js->writeBuffer();` before `</body>`

I am not sure on the exact workings but I *think* your JS is working with `echo` because it is being output in the middle of your `view`, so when the page loads, it `alerts`. (The JS will be in the middle of your HTML output) rather than in the `<head>` or before `</body>`

The `writeBuffer` is being called before the view file is processed; so your `view` js does not get added to the buffer. I could be incorrect however.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but writeBuffer before closing body tag hasn't seemed to help unfortunately.

Comment: +1 for "The general consensus is don't bother using the JsHelper"

Answer (score 0):

Set the write buffer at the end of each ctp file and it should work